# Detect deletion event via SQLite AFTER DELETE trigger when this is executed even if the delete violates a constraint

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, triggers

I have a GUI application with a database backend (Python, sqlite3) and I want to emit events in case of any change to special tables. Because of that, I created AFTER (INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE) triggers that call at their end a self-defined function with the details regarding an event. This worked very well until I observed unwanted behavior.
**If an entity should be deleted and something prohibits this deletion the event is also emitted.**

1. I use strong reference integrity and when a referenced entity should be deleted the database doesn't delete it.
2. I also have BEFORE (DELETE | UPDATE) triggers for enforcing special protection to some data that nobody should be able to change. It seems that this works correctly (If a before trigger fails no event is emitted - the after delete trigger isn't called.)

When I delete an entity with a SQL statement and the reference integrity cancels this deletion the AFTER trigger still emits the event.
This leads to bad behavior.

I have searched a lot for a solution and now I understand the order a bit better.

1. DELETE statement happens
2. constraint cancels
3. AFTER the trigger emits an event
4. My software reacts to the deletion of an entity (at this time even my selects think the entity is gone)
5. Trigger executes ROLLBACK?
6. The program continues (now the selects to find the entity again but the software thinks it is gone)

I don't know how to solve this but I need a way to detect changes.

Maybe there is a way to stop the AFTER trigger from firing on a canceled delete.
In case of no other solution, I would have to not even execute delete from my software when check selects fail but this would be a bit of additional code per entity to find all references and it wouldn't be so nice because direct statement execution wouldn't be affected.

**TO CLARIFY THIS:**
When the function is called by the AFTER trigger inside the function (until the control goes back to SQLite) the entity is as far as I understand not visible to selects but I don't know if starting a short-timer inside another thread from this function (that shoots when the statement is hopefully at an end) would be the only way. I don't like this resulting timing insecurity.

A bit of an example like it could be in my application:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS companies(
  ID integer primary key,
  name text not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(
  ID integer primary key,
  company_id integer not null references companies,
  name text not null,
  UNIQUE(company_id, name)
);

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS trigger_companies_delete
AFTER DELETE ON companies WHEN my_func_triggers_enabled_not_relevant_for_this()

BEGIN

SELECT my_func_entity_deleted("companies", OLD.ID);

END;
```

## EDIT:

Because of some comments that say that this is not reproducible I now want to give an MWE in **python** and this proves my position.

```py
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")


def test_function(scope, id_: int):
    print("--- delete function:", "DELETE TRIGGER called user defined function", "(", scope, id_, ")")
    res = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM companies").fetchall()
    print("--- delete function:", "SELECT in trigger returns", res)


conn.create_function("emitDelete", 2, test_function)
conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;")
conn.execute("""
CREATE TABLE companies(
    ID integer primary key,
    name text not null unique
);
""")
conn.execute("""
CREATE TABLE people(
    ID integer primary key,
    company_id integer not null references companies,
    name text not null,
    UNIQUE(company_id, name)
);
""")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO companies(name) VALUES('testComp');")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO people(company_id, name) VALUES(1, 'testPersA');")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO people(company_id, name) VALUES(1, 'testPersB');")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO people(company_id, name) VALUES(1, 'testPersC');")

conn.execute("""
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS test_trigger 
AFTER DELETE ON companies
BEGIN
SELECT emitDelete('companies', OLD.ID);
END;
""")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("DELETE initiated")
    try:
        conn.execute("DELETE FROM companies WHERE ID = 1")
        print("DELETE finished")
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        print("DELETE failed")
    print("SELECT after finishing delete trigger and statement:",
          conn.execute("SELECT * FROM companies").fetchall())
```

---

## Program output:

```
DELETE initiated
--- delete function: DELETE TRIGGER called user defined function ( companies 1 )
--- delete function: SELECT in trigger returns []
DELETE failed
SELECT after finishing delete trigger and statement: [(1, 'testComp')]
```

This proves that the entity is locked until the trigger ends and that the trigger *is called*.

Comment: Let me understand this. When the deletion fails because the constraint prevents it to happen, but then your application doesn't know about it? Sounds like your triggers are "swallowing" the exception instead of propagating it. The app SHOULD be notified; it's a major situation.

Comment: The triggers main purpose is to inform about a happend deletion but it ist also fired if the deletion was only started and blocked by a constraint. Inside the notified function where the trigger hasn't ended the entity in question is Not visible to selects. When the execution ist ober (a bit later) it is again there without an event. My application could ASK later (after the trigger hast completed) for the entity but IT doesn't because the event sayd that IT IS deleted and No other is emitted. I don't know how to distinguish a failed from a successful deletion.

Comment: The trigger is defined on `people` and there is no referential integrity constraint defined to prevent the deletion.

Comment: people references companies with company ID. I left the pragma for strong integrity out. This ist only an example.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you ment. I change the example.

Comment: I think I understand why you can't reproduce it. After the DELETE statement the entity is locked. Then the trigger is fired and your changes to another table or my user defined function are excuted. At some point (I think after the trigger) the constraint fails and executes ROLLBACK. The changes to your table are undone but my function was already executed. Because of that you can only reproduce it with a python callable that is bound as a sqlite function (create_function)